# How to display this meta data (an array) in form of a function (created with a custom write panel)?

Tags: functions, customization

I'm using the following code to create custom write panels:

```
<?php

$key = "project";
$meta_boxes = array(
    "project_services" => array(
        "name" => "project_services",
        "title" => "Services",
        "description" => "List the services provided for the project."),
    "project_name" => array(
        "name" => "project_name",
        "title" => "Name",
        "description" => "Write the name of the project."),
    "project_overview" => array(
        "name" => "project_overview",
        "title" => "Overview",
        "description" => "Write an overview of the project.")
    );

function create_meta_box() {
    global $key;

    if( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ) ) {
        add_meta_box( 'new-meta-boxes', ucfirst( $key ) . ' Description', 'display_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
    }
}

function display_meta_box() {
    global $post, $meta_boxes, $key;
?>

<div class="form-wrap">

<?php
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), $key . '_wpnonce', false, true );

    foreach($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
?>

<div class="form-field form-required">
<label for="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>"><?php echo $meta_box[ 'title' ]; ?></label>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $meta_box[ 'name' ]; ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] ); ?>" />
<p><?php echo $meta_box[ 'description' ]; ?></p>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
<?php
}

function save_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $meta_boxes, $key;

    foreach( $meta_boxes as $meta_box ) {
        $data[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ] = $_POST[ $meta_box[ 'name' ] ];
    }

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $key . '_wpnonce' ], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
        return $post_id;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
        return $post_id;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $data );
}
```

Now, I can call that metadata in the following way:

```
<?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'project', true ); ?>
<p><?php echo $data[ 'project_services' ]; ?></p>
```

But I would like to call it in this way:

```
<p><?php project_services(); ?></p>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
<?php        
function get_project_services() {    
         global $post;
         $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'project', true );
         $project_services = $data['project_services'];    
         return $project_services;    
}
?>
```

Then in your template file:

```
<p><?php echo get_project_services(); ?></p>
```

I think that will do what you're asking?

(Edited to match your comment.)

Comment: @Chip Bennett thanks but I would just like to display it in this fashion: `<p>project_services();</p>`, just like you do with `the_title();` or `the_content();`

Comment: Okay, I updated the example code. See if that works better? :)

Comment: @Chip Bennett For some reason it doesn't work, it only works if I call it directly from the template.

Comment: Are you calling it from inside the Loop? Oh, might need to declare the global `$post`. Let me update real quick...

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working!